# get items from database using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, list

i'm starting to learn rails, and i'm creating a little website, but i don't know how can i get a list from database.
i have 3 tables:

user
pills
dependent

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many:user_dependents
end

class Dependent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many:pill_dependents
    has_many:user_dependents
end

class PillDependent < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to:pill
    belongs_to:dependent
end
```

How can i get the list of Pills, from all the dependents connected with the user?

Comment: My advice for you is to learn some Rails basics.

Comment: yes, i'm trying to. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: go through a tutorial. every tutorial should tackle this question.

Comment: I would recommend http://railsforzombies.org/ from codeschool. They're very good if you have at least some programming background.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understandig correctly, you want to define a [transitions table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_dependency) connecting *Users* and *Dependents*. In rails you can map this relation automatically by using [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). After you ran the migrations, you can access the *Users* from a *Dependent* by running for example:

```
dependent = Dependent.first
users = dependent.users
```

And the other way arround

```
user = Users.first
dependents = user.dependents
```

Rails does involve a lot of magic. It is necessary to learn about this magic by some tutorials. Otherwise there remain things you just won't get.

I'd recommend [rails for zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) from codeschool. They're very good in explaining the magic.

Comment: defining has_many and belongs_to, should work, but the hard part is create the controler